# Measuring similarity between different length synsets returns a nan

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nltk, wordnet

I have two sets of wordnet synsets (contained in two separate list objects, s1 and s2), from which I want to find the maximum path similarity score for each synset in the first set of synset (s1) onto the second set (s2) with the length of output equal that of s1. For example, if  contains 4 synsets, then the length of output should be 4; on the contrary, when s2 first entering into the function (meaning that s1 swaps position with s2), the length output should equal that of s2.

I have experimented with the following code (so far).

```js
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import pandas as pd

#two wordnet synsets (s1, s2)

s1 = [wn.synset('multiple_sclerosis.n.01'),
 wn.synset('stewart.n.01'),
 wn.synset('head.n.04'),
 wn.synset('executive.n.01'),
 wn.synset('washington.n.02'),
 wn.synset('not.r.01'),
 wn.synset('expect.v.01'),
 wn.synset('attend.v.01')]
 
s2 = [wn.synset('multiple_sclerosis.n.01'),
 wn.synset('stewart.n.01'),
 wn.synset('sixty-one.s.01'),
 wn.synset('information_technology.n.01'),
 wn.synset('head.n.04'),
 wn.synset('executive.n.01'),
 wn.synset('military_officer.n.01'),
 wn.synset('president.n.04'),
 wn.synset('make.v.01'),
 wn.synset('not.r.01'),
 wn.synset('attend.v.01')]
 
# define a function to find the highest path similarity score for each synset in s1 onto s2, with the length of output equal that of s1

ps_list = []
def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    for word1 in s1:
        best = max(wn.path_similarity(word1, word2) for word2 in s2)
        ps_list.append(best)
    return ps_list

similarity_score(s1, s2)  # this one works fine

similarity_score(s2, s1)  # this one returns a nan
```

However, as noted at the last line of my code, when synset s2 (containing 11 synsets) first entering the function, the function returns a nan. I could not figure out what cause the problem, I am sure if this is because I am dealing with synsets of different lengths and some of the synsets in the longer one could not find a match, hence, causing the nan, or there may be something wrong with my for loop.

It will be really appreciated if someone could help clarify this to me and suggest an alternative solution to this (something that will returns a number, a float, to be precise), so that I can apply this function to other synsets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much I can see wrong with your code, except for the usage of the ps_list variable (which doesn't get cleared between calls to similarity_score())

If we change ps_list to a dictionary we can check the best score for each word. The following code does that as a test:

```
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

nltk.download("wordnet", "C:/Users/MackayA/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PythonApplication9/PythonApplication9/nltk_data")
nltk.data.path.append("C:/Users/MackayA/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PythonApplication9/PythonApplication9/nltk_data")

#two wordnet synsets (s1, s2)

s1 = [wn.synset('multiple_sclerosis.n.01'),
 wn.synset('stewart.n.01'),
 wn.synset('head.n.04'),
 wn.synset('executive.n.01'),
 wn.synset('washington.n.02'),
 wn.synset('not.r.01'),
 wn.synset('expect.v.01'),
 wn.synset('attend.v.01')]

s2 = [wn.synset('multiple_sclerosis.n.01'),
 wn.synset('stewart.n.01'),
 wn.synset('sixty-one.s.01'),
 wn.synset('information_technology.n.01'),
 wn.synset('head.n.04'),
 wn.synset('executive.n.01'),
 wn.synset('military_officer.n.01'),
 wn.synset('president.n.04'),
 wn.synset('make.v.01'),
 wn.synset('not.r.01'),
 wn.synset('attend.v.01')]

def similarity_score(set1, set2):
    ps_list = {}
    for word1 in set1:
        best = max(wn.path_similarity(word1, word2) for word2 in set2)
        ps_list[word1] = best
    return ps_list

pprint (similarity_score(s2, s1))
```

This gives the following results:

```
{Synset('attend.v.01'): 1.0,
 Synset('executive.n.01'): 1.0,
 Synset('head.n.04'): 1.0,
 Synset('information_technology.n.01'): 0.07142857142857142,
 Synset('make.v.01'): 0.3333333333333333,
 Synset('military_officer.n.01'): 0.14285714285714285,
 Synset('multiple_sclerosis.n.01'): 1.0,
 Synset('not.r.01'): 1.0,
 Synset('president.n.04'): 0.25,
 Synset('sixty-one.s.01'): None,
 Synset('stewart.n.01'): 1.0}
```

This would seem to suggest that the algorithm cannot find a match of any kind for the s2 'sixty-one.s.01' entry anywhere in s1. It might be worth running more tests on that single entry.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. I also found that my code could not distinguish plurals (for some documents). Still working on that.